# Opening existing Windows while keeping state

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm building an app with a fixed header (`Alloy`, `Android/iOS`), having a few icons like `search/profile/likepage`. This header is appearing on every page like this:

**index.xml (view)**

```
<View id="header">
</View>
```

**index.js (controller)**

```
$.header.add(Alloy.createController('header').getView());
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way because this makes a new instance of it on every page (thus losing state, like if i colored a button in the index it will be reset on the profile-page). I would like to have a solution for this as well (reloading a header on each page with persisting the state of the header)

Next: when I click on the icons in the header, they should open the corresponding view. The app always starts at index.xml (search) on which you can fill in a search form, and clicking the search icon should open this view. It should open the current state of the window with formdata instead of opening a new index with empty formdata.

- How can I share the headerview with persisting state?
- How can I open the active index.xml when it's in the current window stack but not visible (another window is on top)? The Window that is on top should keep existing as well for later use (so I can use another header icon to switch to this view)

I believe those 2 questions are very related to eachother.

- 3rd: how well is the above transferable between iOS/Android?

Thanks for reading!